# MariaDB ODBC connector 3.1.4 (32 bit) with BEGIN NOT ATOMIC

Tags: odbc, mariadb, visual-foxpro

getting an error from a MariaDB server (version 10.3.11) when my query includes a BEGIN NOT ATOMIC.

Query works fine when using mysql ODBC connector 5.3.10 to the same server.

BEGIN NOT ATOMIC SET @CONTEXT_INFO ='HP17 # Nigel:::rentman.opendata@21:rentman.finddata@32';select * from misc; END;

[10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+mariacosmic]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing. That is a bug in MariaDB C/ODBC up to 3.1.5. But you've already filed https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-269 and know this

Comment: yes, i came here to say just that but you beat me to it.  thanks .